# USB encryption login Ubuntu Elementary OS Freya

Tags: security, usb-drive, elementary-os, screen-lock, disk-encryption

I'm a web developer and I know a lot about servers and scripting languages, but I don't know much about Bash and Linux(in comparison).

It's my understanding that it is possible to allow login to a computer when a user attaches a usb key. I was unfortunately not able to make [this](http://www.techienote.com/lock-unlock-ubuntu-desktop-using-usb-drive/) work on my machine, and I began to wonder if it would still be possible for someone to bypass my password(based on [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/192825/how-to-bypass-and-reset-the-password-on-every-operating-system/) article)

I have some very lucrative programs that I want to keep away from prying eyes and I want to know if there is any way to somehow perform a DDoS attack on my machine if a specific usb is not inserted. I don't want the user to be able to do anything at all on my laptop. If anyone has some suggestions. I would be greatly appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody has physical access to your computer, then they can run whatever code they want on it by booting on an alternative media. Or, if you've locked that up, they can pull out the hard disk and plug it into their computer.

You can't prevent people from running code on your computer if they have access to it, but you can prevent them from accessing your data, by encrypting it. Then, if they access your computer, they'll only see the encrypted data, and they won't be able to decrypt it unless they get hold of the encryption key.

Since you're new to Linux, I recommend that you reinstall your distribution and select “full-disk encryption” (or some similar name) during installation. Most distributions, including elementary OS, offer this possibility. While it is possible to convert an installation to be encrypted, it's pretty advanced with a high risk of wiping the data by mistake. So make sure that your backups are up-to-date and reinstall.

The simple way to set up encryption is with a password. The downside of a password is that to be secure, it needs to be sufficiently random, and a sufficiently random password is hard to memorize. A password that isn't random enough could be guessed. A [good compromise](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6095/xkcd-936-short-complex-password-or-long-dictionary-passphrase) is to **[randomly](http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html)** generate a passphrase made of several words (that's [a lot better than the usual bad advice of l33tspe4k+punctuation](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/password_strength.png)).

Linux's disk encryption system ([dm-crypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dm-crypt)) also supports using a “key file”. A key file is essentially a password, but read from a file instead of being typed on the keyboard. The advantage of a key file is that it can be long, random garbage that's impossible to guess (but impossible to memorize, which is why you'd store it on a smartcard or a USB key). As far as I know, common distributions don't offer a turnkey way to set this up, so you have to run the setup manually. See [How to configure LVM & LUKS to autodecrypt partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59487/how-to-configure-lvm-luks-to-autodecrypt-partition) or [How to load LUKS passphrase from USB, falling back to keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19713918/how-to-load-luks-passphrase-from-usb-falling-back-to-keyboard) for instructions.

If you don't want to allow the memorable password that you created at the beginning to unlock the disk, add a long, random, non-memorable, but typable password as another decryption key (`cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda2 'the long random non-memorable but typable password'`). Print out the long random non-memorable but typable password and store the paper in a safe. Test that it works, then remove the memorable password you created at the beginning (`cryptsetup luksRemoveKey`).

Being able to use the USB key to unlock the display when you've already logged in works differently. At that point, the disk encryption key is still in memory, all you need to do is to prove to the computer that you're authorized to use it. For this, a shorter (but still not completely trivial) password is ok, because if the attacker tries to use the password, they'll be limited by how fast your computer accepts attempts. It's an online attack, unlike trying decryption keys, which can be done offline in parallel on specialized hardware.

If you want to use the USB key to unlock your computer nonetheless, the blog post you linked to looks like a reasonable way to do it (I haven't checked all the commands in detail). If you couldn't make it work, I suggest asking a more precise question on this site: what did you do (copy-paste the commands)? What was the exact behavior (copy-paste all messages)?

Your system will still be vulnerable to more advanced attacks. Encryption does not protect against [evil maid attacks](https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2009/10/evil_maid_attac.html). For that, you need to set up secure boot. Basic use of encryption software also does not protect against [cold boot attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack), where the attacker grabs the RAM sticks from a live system and hopes to read the encryption key that's still in it somewhere. There are [Linux kernel patches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_boot_attack#Register-based_key_storage) to avoid storing the key in RAM (it's only stored in CPU registers, which can't practically be extracted by physical means).